# How to build openssl for WinCE whith MSVC2008

Tags: openssl, windows-ce

I need build openssl for WINCE (STANDARDSDK_500(ARMV4I) MSVC2008) for building Qt 4.8.7 with openssl support on the same platform in future! OpenSSL documentation contains building instructions for eMbedded Visual C++ only! So there are 2 solutions IMO

1. Build OpenSSL with  eMbedded Visual C++ ! Question: Are eMbedded Visual C++ and MSVC2008 generating THE SAME OR COMPATIBLE code? OR 2.Build OpenSSL with MSVC2008?Question: Is anybody have sucssessfull builded openssl whith msvc 2008? Any instructions or documentations?